# Couldn't execute query

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote this simple php code to insert information into a databse:

```
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database)
        or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
$username = $_POST['username'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$query="INSERT INTO users(username,firstname,lastname,email,password,gender,age) VALUES($username,$firstname,$lastname,$email,$password,$gender,$age)";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query)
            or die ("Couldnt't execute query.");
```

Why isn't the query being executed ??

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump` the $query variable and execute the query directly?

Comment: I would bet that you need to add `' '` those around string variables in your `$query`

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Always use `'{$variable}'` format to insert variables in strings.

Comment: try `die(mysqli_error());` for a more accurate error message

Answer (score 5):

You have to use quotes around string values

Change

```
$query="INSERT INTO users(username,firstname,lastname,email,password,gender,age) 
        VALUES($username,$firstname,$lastname,$email,$password,$gender,$age)";
```

to

```
$query="INSERT INTO users(username,firstname,lastname,email,password,gender,age) 
        VALUES('$username','$firstname','$lastname','$email','$password','$gender','$age')";
```

**On a side note**: Interpolating query strings and not sanitizing user input is a wide open door for SQL injections. Please learn and use **[prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** instead.

With prepared statement your code might look like

```
...
$query="INSERT INTO users(username,firstname,lastname,email,password,gender,age) 
        VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

// Prepare statement
if (!($stmt = $cxn->prepare($query))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $cxn->errno . ") " . $cxn->error;
}
// Bind parameters
if (!$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $username,$firstname,$lastname,$email,$password,$gender,$age)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
// Execute query
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Comment: I don't know but probably $age is not a string-value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. And you beat me by 10-20 sec on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18037261/1920232 question :)

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO users(username,firstname,lastname,email,password,gender,age) 
    VALUES($username,$firstname,$lastname,$email,$password,$gender,$age)
```

In all likelihood, many values are strings, so they need to be surrounded by single quotes.  And, in all likelihood, the variables themselves don't have the single quotes in them.  Of course, parameter substitution is the way to go.  But, in the meantime, you could try:

```
INSERT INTO users(username,firstname,lastname,email,password,gender,age) 
    VALUES('$username', '$firstname' , '$lastname', '$email', '$password', '$gender','$age');
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't say what error you are getting but try using the insert statements with single quotes like this

```
$query="INSERT INTO users(username,firstname,lastname,email,password,gender,age) VALUES('$username','$firstname','$lastname','$email','$password','$gender','$age')";
```

Also prevent SQL injection (very  important!!).

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions at all would be my reaction to this answer.

Comment: I saw he was using mysqli so edited it . Btw why should we not use mysql_* function ?